# wether i type y/n i always get to the same result. Why?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

yes, i know, this task would need admin privileges, but i didn't not include it because it doesn't affect my problem.

My Problem is:
wether i type "y", "n", "Y" or "N", i always get to

```
:yes
    cls
    set /p usrnm=Enter Username:
```

and i don't know why. Does someone have a solution?

Thank you

```
:start
echo This sets your default Microphone Volume to 70% and runs automatically in background after starting your Computer.

set /p anwsr=Do you wish to continue? (y/n):
If %anwsr%=="y" goto yes
If %anwsr%=="n" goto no
If %anwsr%=="Y" goto yes
If %anwsr%=="N" goto no
If %anwsr%=="" goto start && cls

:yes
cls
set /p usrnm=Enter Username:
If %usrnm%=="" goto yes && cls && echo Username must not be empty!
copy "stop_auto_audio_leveling.bat" "C:\Windows"
copy "invisble.vbs" "C:\Users\%usrnm%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
copy nircmd.exe "C:\Windows"
copy nircmdc.exe "C:\Windows"
goto no

:no
cls
echo Program will now quit. Thank you for using my installer!
pause
exit
```

Comment: If none of the `If`s is entered, execution will continue onward and hit `:yes` by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in `If %anwsr%=="N"` , the contents of `anwsr` are likely to be `N`, not `"N"`.

If none of the `if` commands cause a branch, execution will continue to `:yes` as batch simply executes commands line-by-line.

Solution:

use `If /i "%anwsr%"=="N"`

where the `/i` means `"case-insensitive"

Comment: Also, add something like an unconditional `goto :start` ahead of the `:yes` label (possibly after a "_I don't understand that_" message), so that you never accidentally "run into" the "yes" branch.